# How to sort and group in a triplet RDD spark

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have a data set like:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| property1 | property2 | distance |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|        1  |         1 |   0      |
|        1  |         2 |  .3      |
|        1  |         3 |  .1      |
|        2  |         1 |  .3      |
|        2  |         2 |   0      |
|        2  |         3 |  .1      |
|        3  |         1 |  .1      |
|        3  |         2 |  .1      |
|        3  |         3 |   0      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I need to group this by `property1` and sort it by `distance`. This data set is RDD currently as "results". I have written this code

```
val resultset = results.map{ case (subjectid, compid, distance) => (subjectid, compid, distance.toDouble)}
val groupedBySubjectComps = resultset.groupBy(_._1)
val sortedCompsBySubjectComps = groupedBySubjectComps mapValues { triples =>
  val sortedTriples = triples.sortBy(_._3) 
  val keepOnlyComps = sortedTriples.map(_._2)
  keepOnlyComps
}
```

There is error at sortBy. It says sortBy is not a member of Iterable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`triples` is an [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator), not a collection. According to the Scala docs, Iterator does not have a sortBy method (which makes sense because an iterator is more like a stream of data that just flows through. Consider trying something like:

```
val sortedTriples = triples.toArray.sortBy(_._3)
```

To change it to a collection which can be sorted.

Comment: Thanks. After doing this I got the data like below. res45: Array[(String, Iterable[(String, String, Double)])] = Array((88,CompactBuffer((88,1,12684.226688734707), (88,2,13702.709666563409), (88,3,14031.722801075684), (88,4,9489.601220005912), (88,5,12928.30061500267), (88,6,7350.1744017855945), (88,7,1868.5015906476144),

Comment: How do I convert it to regular RDD with <String, String, Double>

Comment: If you return it to String, String, Double, it will no longer be grouped by `property1`. What specifically do you want the resulting RDD to look like? Do you want the highest/lowest distance for each property? Or something else? If you want to keep everything, that creates the original RDD you had.

Comment: Basically I want to export the RDDs' like a normal csv with only internal values. For ex. (Row1) 88,1,12684.226688734707 (Row2) 88,2,13702.709666563409

Comment: I am able to print with this:-  sortedTriples.map(_._2).collect().foreach(a=> {a.foreach(e=>print(e+"\n"))})  but I need to export the above mentioned data to CSV